# How to make QGIS always add layers with collapsed symbology in TOC

Tags: qgis, symbology, table-of-contents

When I add a load of raster layers into a QGIS project they default to grayscale symbology (which is fine), but some of them randomly are expanded in the TOC. It takes up a lot of space and doesn't really tell me anything useful.

[image: Some layers in the Table of Contents]

Is there a setting to always show added layers as collapsed? I know there is a collapse all button at the top, but that also collapses my groups, which I don't want.

I'm using v3.28.6 but this has been an issue for a long time.

Comment: If you use the same rasters multiple times in multiple projects, do the ones that show the  expanded symbology always enter that way and vice versa for those that don't?  I'm just wondering if it's something different in the particular rasters to look at or is it the overall settings.  You said it's been going on a long time so perhaps there was a time when it didn't?  Perhaps you could rename your QGIS app data profiles folder and see if the new default one fixes things.  You do lose your customizations with the new default but that may be worth the fix.

Comment: I have the same issue when I save my project and reopen it. Some of them are expanded but not always the same ones each time. I could understand if it was all of them or none of them, but why expand just a few?

Comment: Same thing happens when I select a load of layers and choose Group Selected. One of them will pop open. If a layer is collapsed, it should stay collapsed when you move it.